# Github API /Users Identifier Attribute

Tags: github-api

Is there an attribute that I can identify the user from the Github /Users endpoint?

I see two attributes could be the identifier of a user, namely the "id" and "node_id" attributes. The [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/users) does not elaborate further on what these attribute represent, and I have tried researching online to no avail.

Can anyone confirm if there is an Identifier Attribute that I can use from the /Users Github Api?